# Есть ли в свободном доступе датасет(ы) подобные IAM dataset, но на русском языке

Tags: распознавание-символов, dataset

Существуют ли в свободном доступе датасет(ы) рукописных/печатных слов, подобные IAM https://fki.tic.heia-fr.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database для русского языка, который позволит обучить нейромодель для OCR